# Make result box appear after searchbar

Tags: javascript

So, I am creating a website and I need to make a result box appear with a list of possible results after the user searches something in the search bar.
It's something like this: http://s24.postimg.org/4qqgz0t6d/Sem_T_tulo.png

The results box will only appear after the user clicks the "search" button.
I am only looking for the javascript code that makes that box appear. The search algorithm is another problem that I think I can handle.
Do you guys know something that can help me? At least something where I can start from...
Thanks.

Comment: Good place to start is [www.codeacademy.com](http://www.codeacademy.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you down the right path:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                #results-container
                {
                    height:200px;
                    width:400px;
                    border:1px solid #A9A9A9;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="#">
                <input type="text" />
                <button id="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
            <div id="results-container" style="display:none;">
                Results go in here.
            </div>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("results-container").style.display = 'block';
            });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

You would obviously have to handle all of the search related events but this demonstrates how to show the results container after submitting. I also recommend using a javascript framework such as http://jquery.com/ especially if you'll be using AJAX for the dynamic generation of results.